# rails 4 views form syntax error

Tags: forms, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-error, erb

Rails 4, ruby 2.0. 
I want to make a public file serving page with a download link for each file and the possibility to check multiple files for download with checkboxes and a "Download checked files" button.

My code in index.html.erb

```
<% form_tag(controller: "files", action: "download_many", method: "get")%>
<h1>St.Catherines</h1>
  <ul>
<% @stcatherines.each do |file|%>
  <li><%= link_to file, :action => "download", :name =>file %></li>
  <%check_box_tag(file)%>
<%end%>
  <%submit_tag :value => "Download checked files" %>
  </ul>
<%end%>
```

Where @stcatherines is an array of strings
The download link works, something with the form must be wrong. 
I'm stuck with a strange error:

```
  .../app/views/files/index.html.erb:11: 
  syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
```

Note that the syntax error is raised at line 11 and i have only 10 lines of code.

Comment: your submit tag must be <%= submit_tag :value=>"Download checked files" %>. Also you chek_box_tag must be check_box_tag

Comment: @Raghu: Thanks for finding the typo. I edited my code as you suggested but I got still the exactly same error. Edited the question afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you missed opening the `form_tag` and added the end, resulting in the syntax error. Adding a `do` after the `form_tag` declaration should fix it... Try changing your code to the following (note the addition of `do` on line 1):

```
<% form_tag(controller: "files", action: "download_many", method: "get") do %>
<h1>St.Catherines</h1>
  <ul>
<% @stcatherines.each do |file|%>
  <li><%= link_to file, :action => "download", :name =>file %></li>
  <% check_box_tag(file) %>
<% end # each %>
  <%submit_tag :value => "Download checked files" %>
  </ul>
<% end # form_tag %>
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This works. I copied the content from [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html] and didn't get right, that the snippets are only part of the form :) (My english and my programming abilities both still suck ;)